# Updating a nested property on a collection object with $set

Tags: meteor

If one has a collection of objects that look like this:

```
{
    name:"some name",
    dob:"april 4, 1985",
    address:{
        street:"some street",
        city:"some city",
    }
}
```

...can $set be used to update just the city?

Answer (score 0):

This query should do it for you:

```
Collection.update({sel}, {"$set" : {"address.city": "new city"}})
```

Comment: And when the "adress" or/and "city" is a variable, how to do so ?

Comment: just pass the variable instead of the value without the quotes"". here:

Collection.update({sel}, {"$set" : {"address.city": newcity}})

where newcity is the variable.

Comment: in your example, `"new city"`is the variable, but what if the variable is `city`?

Comment: @fraherm how do you update the entire address using a variable ?