# When update nested collection in meteor, how to pass variable for the update path

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteorite

Update a nested collection in meteor is not a problem (and it is described here : [Updating a nested property on a collection object with $set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509888/updating-a-nested-property-on-a-collection-object-with-set))

Basic way to do it :

```
Collection.update({sel}, {"$set" : {"address.city": "new address"}});
```

But what if I want to describe my path with variables ?

This one obviously does not work :

```
var cityName = "NYC";
Collection.update({sel}, {"$set" : {"address." + cityName: "new address"}});
```

Sadly this one does not work either:

```
var path = "address.NYC";
Collection.update({sel}, {"$set" : {path: "new address"}});
```

Neither does that one:

```
var object = {"address.NYC": "new address"};
Collection.update({sel}, {"$set" : object});
```

Well, actually, it works, but not the way I want it. It replace entirely the "address" object, removing the other properties.

Any ideas ?

Is there a way to select the field I want to update in the query part ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because you can't use [dynamic keys for object literals in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500573/dynamic-keys-for-object-literals-in-javascript). You need to use bracket notation and build up the object you want to use in the `update`. For example:

```
var city = 'NYC';
var object = {};
object["address." + city] = 'new address';

MyCollectionName.update(idOfObjectToUpdate, {$set: object});
```

Your last example should work, assuming `Collection` is actually the name of a collection, and `{sel}` is the correct selector for what you are trying to do.

Comment: worked perfectly ; thanks a lot :)

But I am not sure to understand the difference between this and my last attempt. Could you explain ?

Comment: Great - I'm glad that helped. I don't see anything wrong with your last attempt. Building up the object and using a literal should be the same (minus the use of the variable). Perhaps you mistyped something.