# Numeric field names in meteor collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I need to achieve such collection structure:

```js
{
    "_id" : "36JaTS8N9uJDHabaq",
    "pages" : {
        1 : {
            "field1" : "value1",
            "field2" : "value2"
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Everything is fine, when I'm doing the following:

```js
Collection.insert({
    "pages": {
        1: {
            "field1" : "value1",
            "field2" : "value2"
        }
    }
})
```

But when I'm trying to use the variable containing the number instead of number itself, like:

```js
var number = 1;
Collection.insert({
    "pages": {
        number: {
            "field1" : "value1",
            "field2" : "value2"
        }
    }
})
```

I receive not the result I want (there is a variable name where number should be):

```js
{
    "_id" : "SjMotZHrtXviuoyqv",
    "pages" : {
        "number" : {
            "field1" : "value1",
            "field2" : "value2"
        }
    }
}
```

What is the right way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use variables as keys in object literals in javascript. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577825/when-update-nested-collection-in-meteor-how-to-pass-variable-for-the-update-pat/18578075#18578075) answer.

```
var number = 1;
var pages = {};
pages[number] = {f1: 'v1', f2: 'v2'};
Collection.insert({pages: pages});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this :

```
var doc={
    pages:{}
};

var number="1";
doc.pages[number]={
    "field1":"value1",
    "field2":"value2"
};

Collection.insert(doc);
```